# How to run Rust Analyzer directly from terminal?

Tags: rust, language-server-protocol, rust-analyzer

I'm trying to integrate Rust Analyzer with a browser based editor.

My first step is to run Rust Analyzer directly from a terminal and send requests via stdio.

```
$ rust-analyzer
> Content-Length:207\r\n\r\n{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":null,"rootPath":"/mnt/78b33d24-344b-43da-a40c-8b81a6fd0b34/projects/rustexplorer/quick_test","initializationOptions":{},"capabilities":{}}}
```

But I got this error:

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer] Unexpected error: expected initialize request, got Err(RecvError)
expected initialize request, got Err(RecvError)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just because the four literal characters `\` `r` `\` `n` are not transformed into the two special characters `\r` and `\n` when you input them directly in the terminal.

In order to experiment *by hand* in the terminal, you should transform the line ending.

```
$ sed -u -re 's/^(.*)$/\1\r/' | rust-analyzer 
Content-Length: 207

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":null,"rootPath":"/mnt/78b33d24-344b-43da-a40c-8b81a6fd0b34/projects/rustexplorer/quick_test","initializationOptions":{},"capabilities":{}}}

... then the response is displayed here ...
```

Note that we press the `Enter` key here; we do not try to input the `\n` special character.

And on a second thought, I think that in this case (interactive terminal) you should provide `Content-Length: 209` because the json content will be ended with `\r\n` (two more bytes, ignored as separators).
This way, the next request can be input on the next line.
If you keep `207`, then your next request should start on the same line as the json content (right after the last `}`).

Another solution would be to change the settings of the terminal.
`stty -icrnl` makes the `Enter` key produce the `\r` (control-M) character; you then have to input control-J to produce the `\n` character.

```
$ stty -icrnl
$ rust-analyser
Content-Length: 208^M <-- Enter + control-J
^M <-- Enter + control-J
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", ... ,"capabilities":{}}} <-- control-J
... the response is displayed here ...
```